# Pass multidimensional array to extern "C" function as void *

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, strict-aliasing

I have a C function in my library that works with multidimensional arrays nicely:

```
void    alx_local_maxima_u8 (ptrdiff_t rows, ptrdiff_t cols,
                    const uint8_t arr_in[static restrict rows][static cols],
                    bool arr_out[static restrict rows][static cols])
        __attribute__((nonnull));
```

And I have a `unsigned char *` that I receive from a `class` defined in openCV.  That pointer represents a bidimensional data, but it isn't, and I have to use it with pointer arithmetics (`unsigned char *img_pix = img->data + i*img->step + j;`), which I don't especially like.

I create an array of `bool` of the same size of the image (this is a real array, so I can use array notation) to store the results of the function.

I could write an almost exact copy of `alx_local_maxima_u8()` that uses just a pointer and pointer arithmetics, but I'd like to be able to re-use it if I can.

Is it safe to write a prototype that uses a `void *` in this way just to fool C++?:

```
extern "C"
{
[[gnu::nonnull]]
void    alx_local_maxima_u8 (ptrdiff_t rows, ptrdiff_t cols,
                             const void *arr_in,
                             void *arr_out);
}
```

In theory `void *` can hold any pointer which is what C will receive, and C will not access any data that doesn't belong to those pointers, so the only problems I see are aliasing a `unsigned char *` as a `uint8_t *[]`,  and passing a `void *` where a `uint8_t *[]` is expected, which may cause all kind of linker errors.  Also, I don't know if C `bool` and C++ `bool` will translate into the same thing in memory (I hope so).

Maybe I should write a wrapper in C which receives `void *` and passes them to the actual function, so that I don't need to fool C++.

Performance IS a concern, but I use `-flto`, so any wrappers will probably vanish in the linker.

I use GCC (`-std=gnu++17`) in Linux with POSIX enabled.

Comment: Why not just use a portable compatible definition?

Comment: In theory `x[m][n]` and `x[m*n]` are incompatible and not interchangeable in either language, even though the layout is the same. In practice however, the compiler is unlikely to do anything sinister since the data comes from a module not under its control and it doesn't know its "true" type. It must therefore assume you are not lying to it about the type. Of course anything is possible as compilers get progressively smarter.

Comment: @Mgetz If I use a simple pointer in C (just as openCV encodes its 2D image), I would lose the ability of using array notation in C, and that's just a no.  If you know of a prototype that will not force the modification of the definition of the function, that will be valid in both languages, and will not rely on UB, please tell me, because I'm very new in C++ and don't know what I can do with it.

Comment: @n.m. That's what I'm worried about.  In theory the compiler shouldn't be able to know the contents, so it can't do many bad things, but as I use `-flto`, I'm worried that the linker will be able to do those kind of things.  And the linker may have access to all that information.

Comment: @Mgetz If there is a wrapper around the C function that would make this a perfectly defined behaviour in both languages, that would be perfect.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito which is technically a GNU extension. In C `int[]` and `int*` are identical from a parameter perspective

Comment: @Mgetz Something missing in your comment? I don't unserstand the first part.  `int []` decays to `int *`, but `int [][]` decays to `int (*)[]`, and although GCC has VLAs as an extension, it doesn't accept them in function prototypes, so I don't know how I can do something like `void foo(ptrdiff_t n, ptrdiff_t m, int (*a)[m]);` in the gnu++ dialect

Comment: The GNU linker operates on GCC intermediate representation, called GIMPLE, which is to the best of my knowledge is language agnostic. The syntax resembles C but this is not of any significance. I don't think the linker will use strict aliasing rules of C or C++, because not all languages have such rules (but you better ask the developers to be sure). Of course one day it all may change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guarantee that a T[N][M] will contain NxM consecutive objects of type T impedes some otherwise-useful optimizations; the primary usefulness of that guarantee in pre-standard versions of C was that it allowed code to treat storage as a single-dimensional array in some contexts, but a multi-dimensional array in others.  Unfortunately, the Standards fails to recognize any distinction between the pointers formed by the decay of an inner array versus a pointer formed by casting an outer array to the inner-element type either directly or through `void*`, even though they impose limitations on the former which would impede the usefulness of the latter.

On any typical platform, in the absence of whole-program optimization, the ABI would treat a pointer to an element of a multi-dimensional array as equivalent to a pointer to an element of a single-dimensional array with the same total number of elements, making it safe to treat the latter as the former.  I don't believe there is anything in the C or C++ Standard, however, that would forbid an implementation from "optimizing" something like:

```
// In first compilation unit
void inc_element(void*p, int r, int c, int stride)
{
  int *ip = (int*)p;
  ip[r*stride+c]++;
}
// In second compilation unit
int array[5][5];
void inc_element(void*p, int r, int c, int stride);
int test(int i)
{
  if (array[1][0])
    inc_element(array, i, 0, 5);
  return array[1][0];
}
```

by replacing the call to `inc_element` with `array[0][i*5]++`, which could in turn be optimized to `array[0][0]++`.  I don't think the authors of the Standard intended to invite compilers to make such "optimizations", but I don't think they thought aggressive optimizers would interpret a failure to prohibit such things as an invitation.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the array pointer as a `const void *` should not cause any problem, but be aware that `bool` may have a different representation in C and C++. It would be safer to use a more explicit type such as `unsigned char` for the array base type.

Specifying this type for the pointer would also help readability, as matrix cells could be addressed directly using `p[r * cols + c]`.

Comment: It would be insane (at least in POSIX, I wouldn't be surprised if Windows did that) to have different type representations in C and C++.  That would invalidate all `extern "C"` functions using pointers to non-fixed-width types such as `int` or `bool`.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito: There's no guarantee that code generated by one C compiler for a platform would be able to call or be called by a function processed using another C compiler, much less a C++ compiler.  Many platforms have documented recommendations for calling and parameter-passing conventions, but that's not universal.  Especially on 8-bit platforms, calling conventions can vary all over the place even among implementations targeting the same CPU.

Comment: @supercat Luckily, I link statically to my library, so it is compiled with the same compiler (GCC) for both.  Also, this was for a desktop program (amd64), so unlikely to find incompatibilities.  Good to know, though.  It would be better if GCC added VLAs in parameters as an extension, not having to rely on UB :)

Comment: @CacahueteFrito: According to the published Rationale, the authors of the Standard left many things as UB with the intention that many implementations would, as "popular extensions", process them predictably in cases where that would serve their intended purpose.  If an implementation truthfully specifies situations where it will always perform certain function calls in a fashion consistent with the ABI, that specification will define the behavior of such calls even if the Standard doesn't.